# Cannot draw a line above a texture DirectX

Tags: graphics, directx, rendering, directx-9

I'm using directX to draw a serious of textures and now for debugging purposes I want to draw lines around the texture (so to say drawing a rectangle). But the problem is no matter what I try the texture always appears on the top of the lines regardless of the drawing order, and seems the line only got draw on the background, here is the code I use for drawing:

device:

```
LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9       graphicsDevice; // this is used for drawing lines
LPD3DXSPRITE            spriteHandler; // this is used for drawing texture
LPD3DXFONT              textRect; // this is used for drawing texts
```

rendering code:

```
graphicsDevice->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, BACKGROUND_COLOR, 1.0f, 0);
graphicsDevice->BeginScene();
spriteHandler->Begin(D3DXSPRITE_ALPHABLEND);
renderSprites();
renderText();
renderLines();
spriteHandler->End();
graphicsDevice->EndScene();
graphicsDevice->Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);


void DirectXGraphics::renderSprites()
{
    spriteHandler->Draw( texture, 
                     rect,
                     NULL,
                     &position,
                     DEFAULT_ALPHA_COLOR);
}

void DirectXGraphics::renderLines()
{
    graphicsDevice->SetFVF(D3DFVF_XYZRHW|D3DFVF_DIFFUSE);
    graphicsDevice->DrawPrimitiveUP(D3DPT_LINESTRIP, 
                        g_width,                    
                        LINES,              
                        sizeof(VERTEX_LIST));      
}

void DirectXGraphics::renderText()
{
      textFont->DrawText (  spriteHandler, 
                    lpcwstrText, 
                    -1, 
                    &textRect, 
                    DT_LEFT, 
                    fontColor );   
}
```

Interestingly, the textfont is not affected by this problem and is subject to drawing order (maybe it's because I have passed `spriteManager` as a parameter).

My guess is that there might be priority level for different device I'm using to draw and somehow spriteHandler always get to rendered on the top and line can only be seen if the texture size is not big enough to cover that line section (which leaves out the lines along with the grey background too). Any suggestion in working around this?

Answer (score 0):

You could have depth buffer enabled

Try to call:

```
graphicsDevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ZENABLE,D3DZB_FALSE);
graphicsDevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ZWRITEENABLE,FALSE);
graphicsDevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ZFUNC,D3DCMP_ALWAYS);
```

in renderLines (before the draw call), that should normally fix it.

Comment: I added this three lines inside `renderLines()` right before `SetFVF` but didn't seems to fix the problem. Also I have just edited the post and added `renderText()`, which is using a different device `LPD3DXFONT` but it doesn't get affected by the problem.

Comment: If you disable sprite draw, does your lines get rendered properly?

Comment: Yes, if I commented out the lines for sprite drawing the line appears properly, but with the default grey background since there is nothing else to draw

Comment: Also there is a `spriteHandler->Begin(D3DXSPRITE_ALPHABLEND);` before drawing sprite, don't know if that will possibly be affecting the problem. Also, in rendering text I'm actually passing `spriteManager` as a parameter so that maybe why it's not affected

Comment: Yes you can also try to disable alpha blend when rendering your lines, that might help.

Answer (score 0):

I've been through the same problem, frustrating as this doesn't have much info.
Make sure to `spriteHandler->End();` before making any draw calls to the device.

In your example, instead of

`spriteHandler->Begin(D3DXSPRITE_ALPHABLEND);
renderSprites();
renderText();
renderLines();
spriteHandler->End();`

Switch to:

`spriteHandler->Begin(D3DXSPRITE_ALPHABLEND);
renderSprites();
renderText();
spriteHandler->End();
renderLines();`